# How to use rotation with inverse kinematics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, inverse-kinematics

I'm new to Unity, I'm doing a project using inverse kinematics, on one hand (with fingers), and I'm receiving hardware **rotation** data (quaternion), how to move the fingers of my hand if my only input is **rotation** , a quaternion on the *last* finger, and another on the *wrist*!
I'm using the example of the inverse kinematics of Dogzer [here the link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/inverse-kinematics-1829)!

here image of the finger
[my target is on the distal finger, and I want to claculate the angles of the other fingers using only the **ROTATION**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1n4U.jpg)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]

public class InverseKinematics : MonoBehaviour {  

public Transform upperArm;
public Transform forearm;
public Transform hand;
public Transform elbow;
public Transform target;
[Space(20)]
public Vector3 uppperArm_OffsetRotation;
public Vector3 forearm_OffsetRotation;
public Vector3 hand_OffsetRotation;
[Space(20)]
public bool handMatchesTargetRotation = true;
[Space(20)]
public bool debug;

float angle;
float upperArm_Length;
float forearm_Length;
float arm_Length;
float targetDistance;
float adyacent;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {
    if(upperArm != null && forearm != null && hand != null && elbow != null && target != null){
        upperArm.LookAt (target, elbow.position - upperArm.position);
        upperArm.Rotate (uppperArm_OffsetRotation);

        Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross (elbow.position - upperArm.position, forearm.position - upperArm.position);



        upperArm_Length = Vector3.Distance (upperArm.position, forearm.position);
        forearm_Length =  Vector3.Distance (forearm.position, hand.position);
        arm_Length = upperArm_Length + forearm_Length;
        targetDistance = Vector3.Distance (upperArm.position, target.position);
        targetDistance = Mathf.Min (targetDistance, arm_Length - arm_Length * 0.001f);

        adyacent = ((upperArm_Length * upperArm_Length) - (forearm_Length * forearm_Length) + (targetDistance * targetDistance)) / (2*targetDistance);

        angle = Mathf.Acos (adyacent / upperArm_Length) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        upperArm.RotateAround (upperArm.position, cross, -angle);

        forearm.LookAt(target, cross);
        forearm.Rotate (forearm_OffsetRotation);

        if(handMatchesTargetRotation){
            hand.rotation = target.rotation;
            hand.Rotate (hand_OffsetRotation);
        }

        if(debug){
            if (forearm != null && elbow != null) {
                Debug.DrawLine (forearm.position, elbow.position, Color.blue);
            }

            if (upperArm != null && target != null) {
                Debug.DrawLine (upperArm.position, target.position, Color.red);
            }
        }

    }

}

void OnDrawGizmos(){
    if (debug) {
        if(upperArm != null && elbow != null && hand != null && target != null && elbow != null){
            Gizmos.color = Color.gray;
            Gizmos.DrawLine (upperArm.position, forearm.position);
            Gizmos.DrawLine (forearm.position, hand.position);
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawLine (upperArm.position, target.position);
            Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
            Gizmos.DrawLine (forearm.position, elbow.position);
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: In a nutshell: Run forward kinematics on an invisible hierarchy of root->wrist->finger to figure out the IK target.

Comment: I need to use inverse kinematics, the only thing I know is the target (rotation), and with that rotation (quaternion), I must calculate the angles of the fingers, knowing only the target and the rotation of the wrist